# Eager loading an associated record while also joining it in Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have books, each belonging to an author. I'd like to print out a list of books as well as some associated author information. I would, as an initial pass, simply use

```
@books = Book.all
```

In my controller and

```
book.author.name
```

In my view, resulting in `@books.count` separate queries (the "n+1" problem). The solution as recommended is

```
@books = Books.includes(:author)
```

Which reduces it to a constant number of queries.

Now if I needed to filter the book list based on some criteria having to do with the author, I would do in the controller

```
@books = Books.joins(:author).where('name like "%Richler%"')
```

But this reintroduces the "n+1" problem. If I try to fit in `.includes(:author)` in the query, it tries to pull it in twice, and `name` becomes ambiguous. In regular MySQL, I would just use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM books LEFT OUTER JOIN authors ON books.author_id = authors.id
  WHERE authors.name LIKE "%Richler%";
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM books, authors WHERE
  authors.name LIKE "%Richler%" AND books.author_id = authors.id;
```

But short of writing just a SQL query string, what's the Railsish way to accomplish this?

Comment: Milan's example works; I think you just needed to specify the table for name to avoid the ambiguity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
Book.joins(:author).where('authors.name like "%Richler%"').includes(:author)
```

This should fire just two SQL queries.